# Select records for the last 6 months including missing months

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, wdl_month_interval), 'Mon YYYY') AS month 
       ,wdl_size_expiring_kb/1024 AS size_expiring_mb 
FROM WIKI_DATA_LIFESPAN 
AND wdl_month_interval < 0 
AND wdl_month_interval >= -6
```

Which returns the following:

> Sep 2013  0.017578125
>
> Oct 2013  0.3076171875

Although, what the aim of the query is, is to return all of the last 6 months, and if there is no record, return a 0 in place of the wdl_size_expiring_kb variable. I originally thought of using a variable which loops through -6 to -1 to show the last 6 months. But I am not too sure what the most efficient way to do this would be. Anyone able to provide any other thoughts as to what route to take?

Thanks very much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a data densification syntax for this, called a "partition outer join". You select the data set with potentially missing elements (which you have the query for) and partition outer join it to the list of required data values.

The 11.2 docs have a good description and examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25554/analysis.htm#DWHSG02013

Answer (score 0):

you could try something along these lines, first create the sequence 0 .. -6 and then outer join to that:

```
with seq(i) as (
    select 0 i from dual
    union all
    select i-1
    from seq
    where i>-6
)
select TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, seq.i), 'Mon YYYY') AS month ,
  ,wdl_size_expiring_kb/1024 AS size_expiring_mb 
from seq
left join WIKI_DATA_LIFESPAN on (wdl_month_interval = seq.i)
```